# PyQt/Qt: How do I temporarily override the paintEvent() method for a QTextEdit? (What am I doing wrong??)

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am trying to temporarily display a QWebPage in the viewport of a QTextEdit. Here is the pertinent code from my program:

```
class Editor(QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Editor, self).__init__()
        self.webpage = QWebPage(self)
        self.paintwebpage = False

    def showWebPage(self, html):
        self.webpage.mainFrame().setHtml(html)
        self.paintwebpage = True
        self.update()

    def hideWebPage(self):
        self.paintwebpage = False
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.paintwebpage:
            self.webpage.setViewportSize(self.viewport().size())
            painter = QPainter(self.viewport())
            self.webpage.mainFrame().render(painter)
            painter.end()
        else:
            super(Editor, self).paintEvent(event)
```

And it never works. I have tried many variations, including telling it exactly the rectangle to paint, or first painting to an image and then painting the image, etc. It always displays maybe a line or two of the webpage, in strange positions in the viewport. Why can't I get it to overwrite the entire viewport from 0,0? Where am I going wrong?

[I want to display a preview of html code from the editor, without the need for multiple space taking widgets; for example, while the user holds down a certain button, the view will temporarily flip to the preview of the html near the cursor.]

Answer (score 3):

Rather than overloading the paintEvent, you could use a [`QStackedWidget`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html) and just swap the widgets over.
This may be a simpler solution to the problem, as it is only a single call to [`setCurrentIndex`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop) to swap the visible widget.

Comment: Its a good idea, I wasn't aware of such a widget. (Though I would still like to know what I'm doing wrong, so I can better learn how to use paint events for painting widgets.)